# When was a package in python installed?

Tags: python, terminal, package

My computer is a part of a large in-house network and installing packages is done by a different set of guys sitting behind a communication curtain. I had a TensorFlow-GPU version installed, but I guess it was not installed correctly, so I had raised a request to reinstall it correctly. It still does not work now, maybe because it was again reinstalled incorrectly or it might not have been touched at all.

How do I know when a package is installed in python?

Comment: I think you're asking *when* a package is installed, but I think you're really wanting to ask *if* a package is installed. The answer @TarunKolla refers to is a good answer to the question 'when was a package installed?', the answer given by 'enamoria' below is an answer to 'is a package installed?' or 'what version of a package is installed?' for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague and it seems hard to me to really get it. But I will try :D

`How do I know when a package is installed in python?`
`pip show` command would be enough. Try `pip show tensorflow-gpu`, and if tf is installed then it must be some output, otherwise pip will say tf-gpu is not installed.

For the reason of *incorrectly installed*, I think it might be due to many *guys* working on the same environment and mess up others install. My advice is taking a look at `virtualenv`, to create your own environment. You can find many detail tutorial of it on the net, I won't put it here

Answer (score 0):

You can issue `pip show` command which shows information about one or more installed packages.

```
pip show tensorflow-gpu
```

You should be able to see the output like this if tensorflow-gpu package is installed on your system:

```
Name: tensorflow-gpu
Version: 1.1.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: wheel, numpy, mock, werkzeug, six, protobuf
Required-by:
```